# How to make an image moving in JavaScript using paddle keys?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a simple game where the player can move between multiple levels.

The player is an image in my case i tried to move it by using javascript but it's not moving! I have tried multiple websites suggestions but none of them has worked

```js
var avatar = document.getElementByClassName("alien-avatar");
var avatarStyle = document.getComputedStyle("alien-avatar");
var topValue = avatarStyle.getPropertyValue("top").replace("px", "");

function moveDown(element) {
  var eStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element);
  var topValue = eStyle.getPropertyValue("top").replace("px", "");
  element.style.top = (Number(topValue) + 20) + "px";
}

moveDown("element");
// Subtract from the top style attribute to go up
function moveUp(element) {
  var elStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element);
  var topValue = elStyle.getPropertyValue("top").replace("px", "");
  element.style.top = (Number(topValue) - 20) + "px";
}
// Add to the left style attribute to go right
function moveRight(element) {
  var elStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element);
  var leftValue = elStyle.getPropertyValue("left").replace("px", "");
  element.style.left = (Number(leftValue) + 20) + "px";
}
// Subtract from the left style attribute to go left
function moveLeft(element) {
  var elStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element);
  var leftValue = elStyle.getPropertyValue("left").replace("px", "");
  element.style.left = (Number(leftValue) - 20) + "px";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="main-game-table">
  <div class="top-items-wrapper">
    <div class="profile">
      <div class="avatar"></div>
      <span class="nickname">Nickname</span>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">Complated Total Missions</div>
    </div>
    <div class="settings-btn">
      <div class="setting-log"></div>
      <ul class="drop-menu show-sett-drop">
        <li class="setting-btn"><a href="#!">Settings</a></li>
        <li class="exit-btn"><a href="#!">Exit</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!---->
  <div class="game-planets">
    <div class="planet-containers">
      <div class="complated-planet">
        <img src="images/compl-miss.png" alt="">
        <div class="compl-plnt-info" id="planet1-info">
          <div class="stars">
            <img src="images/mission-star-yellow.png" alt="">
            <img src="images/mission-star-yellow.png" alt="">
            <img src="images/mission-star-yellow.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="celeb-message">
            <span>GREAT!</span>
          </div>
          <div class="play-again">
            <a href="#!">play again</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="planet-containers">
      <div class="complated-planet">
        <img src="images/compl-miss.png" alt="">
        <div class="compl-plnt-info" id="planet2-info">
          <div class="stars">
            <img src="images/mission-star-yellow.png" alt="">
            <img src="images/mission-star-yellow.png" alt="">
            <img src="images/mission-star.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="celeb-message">
            <span>nice!</span>
          </div>
          <div class="play-again">
            <a href="#!">play again</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="planet-containers">
      <div class="complated-planet">
        <img src="images/compl-miss.png" alt="">
        <div class="compl-plnt-info" id="planet3-info">
          <div class="stars">
            <img src="images/mission-star-yellow.png" alt="">
            <img src="images/mission-star.png" alt="">
            <img src="images/mission-star.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="celeb-message">
            <span>keep it up</span>
          </div>
          <div class="play-again">
            <a href="#!">play again</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="planet-containers">
      <div class="complated-planet">
        <img src="images/compl-miss.png" alt="">
        <div class="compl-plnt-info" id="planet4-info">
          <div class="stars">
            <img src="images/mission-star-yellow.png" alt="">
            <img src="images/mission-star-yellow.png" alt="">
            <img src="images/mission-star.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="celeb-message">
            <span>nice!</span>
          </div>
          <div class="play-again">
            <a href="#!">play again</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="planet-containers">
      <div class="current-planet">
        <div class="alien-avatar" style="
                             width:100%; 
      height:100%;
     top:0px; 
      left:0px;
                        "><img src="images/default-avatar.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="box" style="--n:20;--b:5px;width:150px;--c:#2beeff"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="planet-containers"></div>
    <div class="planet-containers"></div>
    <div class="planet-containers"></div>
    <div class="planet-containers"></div>
  </div>
  <button class="start-btn">start</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

any help would be highly appreciate it!
please note that im still a beginner in this field

Comment: There is nothing like `getElementByClass` in javascript. I think you were tying to use this `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: Is this the complete javascript code, because there is nothing with the name of `alien` in there, still you are using it.

Comment: yes i is the complete js file, i used "alien-avatar" in the begining

Comment: What does this mean `alien - avatar` also there is no variable named `alien`, so how are you using it.

Comment: There's `var avatar = document.getElementByClass("alien-avatar");` twice (+ the non-existing method), and this ReferenceError error: `document.getComputedStyle(alien - avatar);`

Comment: im using it from html class="alien-avatar" @ManasKhandelwal

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal I guess that was the class name with missing quotes that got separated by the _"Tidy"_ feature

Comment: i edited the getELementByClass to getElementByClassName

Comment: @Andreas That got separated because it was interpreted as subtraction because he has put no quotes around it.

Comment: That's not a [mcve], so please fix it first (+ the obvious and already mentioned problems)

Comment: i added the missing quotes but there is no difference!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `getComputedStyle` to remember what the position of an element is, but I would recommend keeping track of your elements positions in your code and not just in the HTML/CSS. Just a short example:

```
let avatar = document.getElementById("alien-avatar");
let avatarx = 20;
let avatary = 20;

function movePlayerUp() {
  avatary--;
  avatar.style.top = avatary + "px";
}
```

Update

You can also use `getBoundingClientRect` to check an element's position in the DOM

```
function moveRight() {
    let position = avatar.getBoundingClientRect();
    let newposition = position.x + 10;
    avatar.style.left = newposition + "px";
}
```

The player element needs an id.

```
<div id="alien-avatar"...></div>
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this example, but just a note can i use Id instead of ClassName in my js?

Comment: You use `id` to get just one element (the player). `getElementsByClassname` will give you an array of all elements with that class name.

Comment: sorry for asking too much question, but dont we need to call the function moveRight() this way? or is there another way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I gave two suggestions, one is by keeping track of the position in a variable, and the other way is to request the current position using getBoundingClientRect.